# Calling full functionality private functions from public functions

Tags: c#, class-design

I have been programming my classes in the following mode. I create a public function that has a call to a private function that has all the logic and functionality. Something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string DoStuff()
    {
        return ActuallyDoStuff();
    }

    private string ActuallyDoStuff()
    {
        string result = "";
        //Do stuff
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is something I inherited from control events in Winforms. If I made an control event I used to create a new function separately or, if the event was replicating a functionality already in use I just called the needed function.

This way if I had to change some functionality I didn't need to change it everywhere, just in one place.

Now I'm instinctively doing the same with public functions in my classes but the more I think about it the more I think this is unnecessary.

Is there any standard or good practice for this case in particular?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This way if I had to change some functionality I didn't need to change it everywhere, just in one place.
>
> Now I'm instinctively doing the same with public functions in my classes but the more I think about it the more I think this is unnecessary.

If your public method only contains **one** private method call (which passes any parameters through blindly), and this private method call is only called from that **one** public method; then the added layer is irrelevant. The public method is just a passthrough to get to the private method.
You can simply make the private method public and it will work the exact same way.

If the public method only contains **one** private method call (which passes any parameters through blindly), but the private method is called from multiple locations, then the same answer still applies. The public method is just a passthrough to get to the private method.
You can simply make the private method public and it will work the exact same way. All calling locations will still be able to access the method. If you keep this public+private setup,

If the public method has other responsibilities (e.g. validation checks, collecting the input parameters to be used in the private method, calling multiple private methods, ...) then separating the private method from the public method makes sense, as they each have their own responsibility. The public method is not just a passthrough to get to the private method.

In short: **You can remove the public method layer if its only job is to blindly pass through to the inner private method**. Empty wrappers have no purpose*.

---

> Is there any standard or good practice for this case in particular?

**Don't add something to the codebase if it doesn't add value to the codebase**. Passthrough methods (= methods which merely provide access to a private method within the same class, without any additional responsibilties) do not have any inherent value*.

---

*The one fringe exception here is that if you're dealing with a method in a class that implements *multiple* interfaces, in which the method can be used for both interfaces, but the two interfaces define a different name for this method, then you will be required to make `SecondInterfaceMethod` a wrapper method around `FirstInterfaceMethod` (or vice versa, or have them both pass through to a third private method) in order to comply with both `FirstInterface` and `SecondInterface`. But this is not a common scenario to encounter.

In this case, you can argue that "fulfilling the other interface contract" is sufficient value for the passthrough method to no longer be considered irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

As it is, this practice serves no purpose. It could make sense if you have many external commands that actually perform the same internal action, but even then I wouldn't write my class that way preemptively.

Answer (score 1):

I see no advantage as you've illustrated it, but it's very similar to a common C++ pattern called non-virtual interfaces (NVI).

With NVI, you offer a public interface that's implemented in terms of virtual methods that are kept private.  Sometimes those will map 1-to-1, as you've shown, but sometimes they won't.

The intent is to separate the definition of the public interface from the customization points offered to derived classes (which, in a sense, is another interface).  That preserves flexibility and keeps details of each interface from leaking into the other interface.

The best reference I know for NVI is [Herb Sutter's article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm).

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a use-case for this pattern. You can adopt that pattern for sections of code that require invocation both privately *and* publicly thereby enhancing *readability*. If you have a private or public method that delves straight into implementation, then you know that the section of code they contain are called in said instances. If you use the wrapper pattern shown in the original post, then you know that the section of code is used internally and externally and infers additional knowledge to the reader.